# Text/Link alignment inconsistent between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, image, vertical-alignment

If you look at the footer on [www.jrsteelers.com](http://www.jrsteelers.com), it looks fine in Firefox. In Chrome, however, the Facebook and Twitter links don't align properly.  I'm using Firefox 11 and Chrome 18.x.  I haven't checked IE yet.

What's going on?  I used Firebug to get some more insight but I'm stumped.

Link: [Screencap of what I'm seeing](http://i1071.photobucket.com/albums/u517/prosnookerproducts/Misc/03042012_52658PM-1.png)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Please show the html and css code for the content in question so we don't have to go digging for it.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick within Chromes console.
`<span>` like us on Facebook at `</span>`

Comment: Wow, awesome and thanks for solving this issue.  I definitely would not have come up with that solution!